# Is there a way in F# to type-test against a generic type without specifying the instance type?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to pattern match against a few types that I care about for SQL generation. Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
let rec getSafeValue record (prop: PropertyInfo) = 
    match prop.GetValue(record, null) with
    | :? string as str -> "'" + str + "'"
    | :? Option<_> as opt -> 
        match opt with
        | Some v -> getSafeValue v prop
        | None -> "null"
    | _ as v -> v.ToString()
```

The problem is that here, the type parameter to `Option<_>` gets constrained to match that of `record`, which ends up being just `obj`.

I know I can do some pain-in-the-behind reflection-based check (check that it's a generic type and that it's an option type based on the name), but I'd rather avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's no good way to do this using F#'s built-in constructs.  However, you could build your own reusable active pattern for this sort of thing:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let (|UC|_|) e o =
  match e with
  | Lambdas(_,NewUnionCase(uc,_)) | NewUnionCase(uc,[]) ->
      if (box o = null) then
        // Need special case logic in case null is a valid value (e.g. Option.None)
        let attrs = uc.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof<CompilationRepresentationAttribute>, false)
        if attrs.Length = 1
           && (attrs.[0] :?> CompilationRepresentationAttribute).Flags &&& CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue <> enum 0
           && uc.GetFields().Length = 0
        then Some []
        else None
      else 
        let t = o.GetType()
        if FSharpType.IsUnion t then
          let uc2, fields = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(o,t)
          let getGenType (t:System.Type) = if t.IsGenericType then t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() else t
          if uc2.Tag = uc.Tag && getGenType (uc2.DeclaringType) = getGenType (uc.DeclaringType) then
            Some(fields |> List.ofArray)
          else None
        else None
  | _ -> failwith "The UC pattern can only be used against simple union cases"
```

Now your function might look something like this:

```
let rec getSafeValue (item:obj) = 
    match item with
    | :? string as str -> "'" + str + "'"
    | UC <@ Some @> [v] -> getSafeValue v
    | UC <@ None @> [] -> "null"
    | _ as v -> v.ToString()
```

Comment: that's a neat way to do it. i ended up doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work in F# without covariance. Assuming that you're happy for `v` to be of type `obj`, you want to be able to treat `Option<anything>` as if it was `Option<obj>`. Without covariance, `Option<anything>` and `Option<obj>` are independent types.

Comment: Just to be clear, .NET (and thus F#) doesn't actually have covariance.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam - .NET (as of 4.0) *does* have covariance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx. I think the reason it wasn't implemented in F# 2.0 is because F# had been primarily targeting .NET 2.0 at the time of release.

Answer (score 0):

When I put your code in F# Interactive, it seems to make 'record' a generic param.  Maybe it works differently in the normal compiler.  Anyway, it is probably picking up that `obj` type due to the first argument of `GetValue` being type `obj`.

I'm sorry I can't test this right now, but give this a shot.  The `box` function uses a generic param, so that might do the trick.

```
let rec getSafeValue record (prop: PropertyInfo) = 
    match prop.GetValue(box record, null) with
    | :? string as str -> "'" + str + "'"
    | :? Option<_> as opt -> 
        match opt with
        | Some v -> getSafeValue v prop
        | None -> "null"
    | _ as v -> v.ToString()
```

Comment: same deal - it constrains both record and opt to type 'a

Answer (score 0):

Some v -> getSafeValue v prop will only work if v is of the same type as record. (or deriving from that that type) otherwise the first line will fail. you can't say prop.GetValue(record,null) unless the property pointed to by prop makes sense (aka is part of the type) in the context of the first argument.

If it's the same type you can do:

```
let rec getSafeValue (record:'a) (prop: PropertyInfo) = 
    match prop.GetValue(box record, null) with
    | :? string as str -> "'" + str + "'"
    | :? Option<'a> as opt -> 
        match opt with
        | Some v -> getSafeValue v prop
        | None -> "null"
    | _ as v -> v.ToString()
```

but if the type of v is derived from 'a it will match the last case so for the above to work they'd need to be exactly the same type