# How to downcast from obj to option<obj>?

Tags: f#, casting

I have a function that takes a parameter of type object and needs to downcast it to an `option<obj>`.

```
member s.Bind(x : obj, rest) =
    let x = x :?> Option<obj>
```

If I pass (for example) an `Option<string>` as `x`, the last line throws the exception: *Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption'1[System.String]' to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption'1[System.Object]'.*

Or, if I try a type test:

```
member s.Bind(x : obj, rest) =
   match x with
    | :? option<obj> as x1 -> ... // Do stuff with x1
    | _ -> failwith "Invalid type"
```

then `x` never matches `option<obj>`.

In order to make this work, I currently have to specify the type the option contains (e.g. if the function is passed an `option<string>`, and I downcast the parameter to that rather than `option<obj>`, the function works.

Is there a way I can downcast the parameter to `option<obj>` without specifying what type the option contains? I've tried `option<_>`, `option<#obj>`, and `option<'a>` with the same results.

By way of background, the parameter needs to be of type `obj` because I'm writing an interface for a monad, so Bind needs to bind values of different types depending on the monad that implements the interface. This particular monad is a continuation monad, so it just wants to make sure the parameter is `Some(x)` and not `None`, then pass `x` on to rest. (The reason I need the interface is because I'm writing a monad transformer and I need a way to tell it that its parameter monads implement bind and return.)

**Update:** I managed to get around this by upcasting the contents of the option before it becomes a parameter to this function, but I'm still curious to know if I can type-test or cast an object (or generic parameter) to an option without worrying about what type the option contains (assuming of course the cast is valid, i.e. the object really is an option).

Comment: I've done some extra formatting on your question, you might like to check out the source (edit) button, to see some of the markdown tricks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151099/is-there-a-way-in-f-to-type-test-against-a-generic-type-without-specifying-the-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f

Comment: Thank you kvb, those do indeed look helpful. I spent a while digging for such information before posting this question, but of course having to use the word "option" turned up a lot of unrelated results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't any nice way to solve this problem currently.

The issue is that you'd need to introduce a new generic type parameter in the pattern matching (when matching against `option<'a>`), but F# only allows you to define generic type parameters in function declarations. So, your only solution is to use some Reflection tricks. For example, you can define an active pattern that hides this:

```
let (|SomeObj|_|) =
  let ty = typedefof<option<_>>
  fun (a:obj) ->
    let aty = a.GetType()
    let v = aty.GetProperty("Value")
    if aty.IsGenericType && aty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = ty then
      if a = null then None
      else Some(v.GetValue(a, [| |]))
    else None
```

This will give you `None` or `Some` containing `obj` for any option type:

```
let bind (x : obj) rest =   
    match x with    
    | SomeObj(x1) -> rest x1
    | _ -> failwith "Invalid type"

bind(Some 1) (fun n -> 10 * (n :?> int))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tomas. That does work for me and it's good to know I wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks to all for the quick replies.

Comment: Pattern matching can be nested to test for `option`s of specific types. Line 3 could be changed to `| SomeObj(:? string as x1) -> rest x1` to test for `option<string>`, for example.

Comment: Try `match None with SomeObj x -> printfn "%A" x | _ -> printfn "Not an option"`. It doesn't handle `None`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain why you need to get your input as obj, but if your input is an Option<_>, then it is easy:

```
member t.Bind (x : 'a option, rest : obj option -> 'b) =
    let x = // val x : obj option
        x
        |> Option.bind (box >> Some)
    rest x
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ramon. My input has to be type obj because I need to accept, for instance, either a string or an option<string>. If I simply use 'a for the input type, then F# complains when any type of option is passed in (i.e. it says it was expecting an 'a but got an 'a option). Using obj as the param type is the only way I've found to get around this. I'm certainly open to a better way of doing it.

Comment: (Ran out of room in the last reply.) Since x is specified as obj in the interface definition for Bind, I'm not able to use the code you mention, as Option.bind(box >> Some) causes the error: Type mismatch. Expecting a obj -> 'a but given a 'b option -> 'c option. The type 'obj' does not match the type ''a option'.

Comment: I see your problem. If you don't like upcasting contents before, or Tomas's reflection (which is probably the correct method), you can use a customized version of the F# compiler which supports more methods than just `Bind` in monads. This, for example, is one option: http://ramon.org.il/wp/2011/04/taking-computation-expressions-one-step-further/

Comment: Thank you very much for the link Ramon, that looks like interesting reading and I'm looking forward to it, especially your implementation of the compiler extension.

Comment: This all started because I wanted to find a way to "stack" multiple monads, i.e. abstract out multiple orthogonal concerns (such as continuation and logging) from the same piece of code. As I understand it you can do this fairly easily in Haskell (http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/05/grok-haskell-monad-transformers.html) but not so easily in F#. But I think I have something basic working at this point and might try posting it as a reply here after some more testing. Thank you again.

Comment: Looks like that's out. The problem just gets uglier with a state monad, where I have to bind a function of ('state -> 'a * 'state) to that x parameter rather than just an int or string option. It's getting ugly and, worse, I don't think I can protect the end user of the monad transform from the ugliness, so they're not going to want to bother with it.

Ramon, are you thinking of writing up a post at some point on how you extended the compiler? That definitely looks interesting. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a specific idea, I could try.

Comment: Hi Ramon, I was just curious about how you extended the F# compiler to accept additional keywords inside the monad (match@!, with@!, and so on). Thank you.

Comment: Well, you have to add cases to the AST algebraic type, add cases in the FsLex file, add cases in the FsYacc file and then you need to write add cases to all match-expressions for your new AST construct. I like to find a similar AST case (if you add a keyword to a monad, choose the case of let! for example), use a program like Windows Grep to find all occurrences and add cases to the match-expressions that will handle the new keyword.

You can download the source for my extension and see how I did it. It is quite simple.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers Ramon. I did indeed download the .zip files from your post, but unless I'm mistaken they include the source for the enhanced monads and only the binaries for the modified F# compiler. Nonetheless I can look at the binaries in Reflector and your comments definitely give me a place to start investigating. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question: you can use a slight variation of Tomas' code if you need a general-purpose way to check for options without boxing values beforehand:

```
let (|Option|_|) value = 
  if obj.ReferenceEquals(value, null) then None
  else
    let typ = value.GetType()
    if typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<option<_>> then
      let opt : option<_> = (box >> unbox) value
      Some opt.Value
    else None
//val ( |Option|_| ) : 'a -> 'b option    

let getValue = function
  | Option x ->  x
  | _ -> failwith "Not an option"

let a1 : int = getValue (Some 42)
let a2 : string = getValue (Some "foo")
let a3 : string = getValue (Some 42) //InvalidCastException
let a4 : int = getValue 42 //Failure("Not an option")
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it's good to have code that shows how to handle some of these pattern matches that, as Tomas says, otherwise only work up at the function declaration level.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code no longer compiles in F# 3.0: Active pattern '|Option|_|' has a result type containing type variables that are not determined by the input. The common cause is a when a result case is not mentioned, e.g. 'let (|A|B|) (x:int) = A x'. This can be fixed with a type constraint, e.g. 'let (|A|B|) (x:int) : Choice<int,unit> = A x'