# Casting a generalized type to its underlying discriminated union if it is one

Tags: casting, f#, discriminated-union

For debugging purposes I need a bit more detail on floats than `printfn "%A"` is giving me and all my test code is generalized. So I figured I `box` and match on the type to get meaningful output.

However, the type can be an option type or a `Result<_, _>` type (Success/Fail). These types only pattern-match when you treat them as discriminated unions, but if I type-test them they won't be hit:

```
// Illustrative example of what I'm trying to achieve (I think)
let rec mkStr v =
    match box v with
    | :? double as dbl -> Str.fromFloat dbl
    | :? int64 as i -> i.ToString()
    | _ -> 
        match v :> obj with 
        | :? Result<_, _> as res ->   // this will never succeed
            match res with
            | Success s -> mkStr s
            | Fail _ -> "Fail"
        | x ->  
            x.ToString()
```

I've tried a variety of boxing/unboxing/casting, the above is one of these varieties. When I debug I can clearly see that a `Success` is passing through, the debugger doesn't even show it's a `Result`. I know that each discriminator in the DU is itself a type, so I understand what's happening, but how can I tell the compiler to "treat as" DU if it sees it matches one of `Success` or `Fail`?

TLDR: given a generalized type, how can I test and cast the type to the underlying DU, if there is any?

(PS: I realize that this is normally not the way to go about DU's, but just like `printf "%A"` exists, I assume that occasionally this is needed, as in this situation)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3151099/82959, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39875110/82959, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2140079/82959.

Comment: @kvb, I was already afraid I'd need reelection. Nice solution though, with the active pattern and quotations. Thanks. Not sure why i didn't find it with Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using quotations to get pattern matching support that @kvb posted in the comments is a nice trick. I had similar problem in the past and used a slightly different trick - rather than using reflection to deconstruct and inspect the value, you can use reflection to invoke a generic method with the right type argument. Here is a minimal example:

```
type MakeString = 
  static member Make<'T>(o:'T) =
    match box o with
    | :? float as f -> sprintf "Float: %A" f
    | o ->
        if typeof<'T>.Name = "FSharpOption`1" then
          let tys = typeof<'T>.GetGenericArguments()
          typeof<MakeString>.GetMethod("MakeOption")
            .MakeGenericMethod(tys).Invoke(null, [| o |]) :?> string
        else
          failwith "Unknown"

  static member MakeOption<'T>(o:option<'T>) =
    match o with
    | None -> "None"
    | Some v -> "Some " + MakeString.Make(v)

MakeString.Make(Some 3.14)
```

When `Make` is called with a value that is of type `option<'T2>` for some `'T2` that we cannot statically know, we find `'T2` using reflection by looking at the generic type arguments and then we invoke `MakeOption` with `'T2` as the type argument - so inside `MakeOption`, we now (again) know the static type of the value contained inside the option.

The one possible advantage of this is that it all works using the static types and so it will work for free when the value is represented as `null` (and so directly calling `None.GetType()` throws an exception). The [previous answer posted by @kvb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151099/is-there-a-way-in-f-to-type-test-against-a-generic-type-without-specifying-the) handles this too, but using a special case for this situation.

Comment: Looks like kvb had `null` covered, he wrote: _"Need special case logic in case null is a valid value (e.g. Option.None)"_. This looks like a good workable solution. Is it a general rule that `\`1` is the suffix for a generic type?

Comment: _(wow, didn't realize I'd manage to get the backtick right inside backticks)_

Comment: It also looks like both you and kvb are emphasizing that the problem is due to generics and not because F# hides the DU concrete types?

Comment: @Abel - The problem is not specific to DUs - you have the same issue when you want to detect, say, `seq<'T>` for any `'T` - you'd need the same tricks to do that. Now, F# could have some power-pattern-matching-on-generics feature that would let you do that, but it does not at the moment :)